# Maintaining folder structure while minifying using grunt

Tags: gruntjs

I have built an application using javascript. I have multiple .js files that are managed across multiple folders and sub-folders. I minified and uglified them using grunt-contrib-uglify. It does it pretty well. But my problem is that it iteratively goes through every .js file and minifies them but rather than maintaining folder structure,all of the minified js files are placed in a single destination folder.
For example:-
I have a JS folder.It has 5 sub-folders-
a,b,c,d,e 
Each one is having 60-70 .js files . Now when I minify them, these all are minified and placed in a single JS-Min folder. But the folder structure is all gone.

Please suggest a way using which I can maintain the folder and sub-folder structure. I searched for it at grunt's official site,but to no solution.

My Gruntfile.js is as follows-

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
  requirejs_obfuscate: {
    options: {
      mangle: true,
        dir: 'jsm',
        salt: 'salt',
        root: 'gruntfiles',
        length: 6,
        quotes: 'double',
         concurrency: 2,
        keepLinefeeds: false,
        keepIndentations: false,
        encodeStrings: true,
        encodeNumbers: true,
        moveStrings: true,
        replaceNames: true,
        variableExclusions: [ '^_get_', '^_set_', '^_mtd_' ],

    }
  },
jsObfuscate: {
    test: {
      options: {
        concurrency: 2,
        keepLinefeeds: false,
        keepIndentations: false,
        encodeStrings: true,
        encodeNumbers: true,
        moveStrings: true,
        replaceNames: true,
        variableExclusions: [ '^_get_', '^_set_', '^_mtd_' ]
      },
      files: {
      src:'jsm/*.js' , // source files mask
      dest:'jso/',
        strings: true,
            expand: true,    
            flatten: true,
            ext: '.js'   
           }
  }
},
    uglify: {
    mangle:{all:true},
    squeeze: {dead_code:true},
    codegen: {quote_keys: true},
      files: { 
             cwd: 'js/',
             src: ['*.js', '**/*.js'],
             dest:'jsm/',
             strings: true,
             expand: true,
             flatten: true
          }
       }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-minified');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-encoding');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-requirejs-obfuscate');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('js-obfuscator');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify','requirejs_obfuscate']);
};
```

Comment: Please help. I am still struck